# Java product and plugin in eclipse require different library versions

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, swtbot

I am trying to test an eclipse product with the Java SWTBot, unfortunetly the product i am testing defines plenty of libraries in the target plattform, like older versions of `org.eclipse.jface` or `org.junit`.

Now i cannot setup the SWTBot in eclipse, how can i configure the startup so that i have e.g. two versions of the junit library (4.10 & 4.12). I tried adding an additional jUnit library, but i cannot reference it as plugin dependency or import it as package.

```
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder 2 0 2017-03-13 14:04:57.536
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.junit_4.12.0.
```

Best regards,
John